# Proving $\{\langle a^N,b \rangle\}_{N=1}^\infty $ is bounded and therefore $a \in \ell^2$ where $a^{N} = (a_1,a_1,\dots, a_{N},0,0\dots)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{C}$ such that for all
> $b=\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^2$, we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty
>  a_n\bar{b_n}$ converges.
>
> Let $a^{N} = (a_1,a_1,\dots, a_{N},0,0\dots)$.
>
> Prove that for all $b\in \ell_2$, the sequence $\{\langle a^N,b
>  \rangle\}_{N=1}^\infty $ is bounded and use this to prove that $a \in
>  \ell^2$.

I initially thought of showing that the sequence is Cauchy (since every Cauchy sequence is bounded), but it seems that this might not be the right direction (the data on the convergence of the sequence is not enough for this, unless I'm missing something).

Then I thought of assuming that it *is* bounded in order to prove the last part, but I'm not too sure about my direction here either as it doesn't actually use this fact. I thought of stating something like: $\{\langle a^N,b\rangle\}_{N=1}^\infty $ is a sequence of functionals, which is converging in $\mathbb{C}$ (since it's, hopefull, Cauchy?). This would mean that $(a^N)_{N=1}^\infty$ is weakly converging, and therefore has a converging subsequence. Denote its limit as $\hat{a} \in \ell^2$. Since the limit is unique and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\bar{b_n}$ converges then it must be $a$.
Am I on the right track here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The methods suggest applying the uniform boundedness principle. Are you familiar with that ? The result can be proved straightforward as well.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Not familiar with that one. Is there another way that doesn't require that theorem?

Comment: Yes there is a way, but then the hint is not applied, in natural way. It goes by contradiction, i.e. Assuming $a\notin \ell^2$ we construct $b\in \ell^2$ such that the series diverges.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc How would you prove the hint? It's not Cauchy, $(a_n)$ is not in $\ell^2$ so Cauchy-Schwartz is not an option... what else could yield something like $... \leq ||b||$ or another inequality that depends only on $b$?

Comment: Something with $b_n$ taking the sign of $a_n$, perhaps, and using the given convergence for all $b$? But then $b$ is not necessarily in $\ell^2$

Comment: I can prove the hint basing on uniform boundedness theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle If you are interested I can post an answer or you can manage yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go!

Answer (score 1):

**For the hint:**

Let $b \in \ell^2$.

$$ | \langle a^N,b \rangle | \leq \sum_{i=1}^N |a_nb_n| = \sum_{i=1}^N a_n sgn(a_n)|b_n| =: (*)$$.

Denote by $\hat{b}$ the sequence such that: $\hat{b_n}:=sgn(a_n)|b_n|$, then $\hat{b} \in \ell^2$ since:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\hat{b_n}|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |sgn(a_n)|b_n||^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^2 < \infty$.

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ converges for all $b \in \ell^2$, it converges for $\hat{b}$. Since for such $\hat{b}$ all summands are non-negative, we have:

$$ (*) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\hat{b_n} < \infty$$

which holds for all $N$.

**For the second part:**

Since $ \big(\langle a^N,b \rangle \big)_N$ is a bounded sequence for every $b$, then, by definition, $(a^N)_N$ is weakly bounded. Since every weakly bounded sequence has a converging subsequence, $(a^N)_N$ has a weakly converging subsequence $(a^{N_k})_k$, meaning $ \big(\langle a^{N_k},b \rangle \big)_{N_k}$ converges to some $ \langle \hat{a},b \rangle $, where $\hat{a} \in \ell^2$.

But $ \big(\langle a^{N_k},b \rangle \big)_{N_k}$ is a subsequence of $ \big(\langle a^{N},b \rangle \big)_{N}$, which, by hypothesis, converges ($\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_nb_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n < \infty$), and therefore they must converge to the same limit, meaning:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n = \langle \hat{a},b \rangle$$

for all $b \in \ell^2$.

So it must be the case that $a_n=\hat{a_n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (e.g., plug in $b=e_n=(0,0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots)$ the unit element).